# Reemplazar NaN en una matriz

Tags: matlab

Tengo estos datos

```
Mat=[1 2 3 5;6 7 -9999 9;10 11 12 13;14 -9999 16 17;18 19 -9999 -9999]
Mat(Mat<0)=NaN

Mat =
1     2     3     5
6     7   NaN     9
10    11    12    13
14   NaN    16    17
18    19   NaN   NaN
```

Como podria reemplazar solo los NaN con el valor promedio de los valores de su izquierda y derecha

```
Mat =
1     2     3     5
6     7     8     9
10    11    12    13
14    15    16    17
18    19   NaN   NaN
```

Lo que me complica es que es importante la ubicacion de los NaN y sus respectivos valores adyacentes, por ejemplo para el NaN(2,3), tiene que ser reemplazado por 7 y 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una manera *burda*, pero funcional, sería algo como esto:

```
Mat=[1 2 3 5;6 7 -9999 9;10 11 12 13;14 -9999 16 17;18 19 -9999 -9999];
Mat(Mat<0)=NaN;
[idx,jdx] = find(isnan(Mat));
for k=1:length(idx)
    try
        Mat(idx(k),jdx(k)) = mean([Mat(idx(k),jdx(k)-1),Mat(idx(k),jdx(k)+1)]);
    catch err
        continue;
    end
end
```

Donde la idea es lo siguiente: primero utilizar la función `find` para obtener todas las posiciones de los `NaN`. Enseguida iterar sobre los índices `(i,j)` que se obtuvieron, e ir tratando de hacer la sustitución correspondiente, es probable que en algún caso los índices estén fuera de los límites de la matriz y   por ello se usa `try-catch` para cuando eso suceda la ejecución no se detenga,  continúe con otro elemento y en el actual no se realice cambio alguno.